# Calling a form from a pushbutton using only QtDesigner

Tags: qt, qt-designer, qt4.8

I have created a form. I have many 2 push buttons. On clicking on a pushbutton I want to call another custom form. I am using only QtDesigner. I am NOT using QtCreator. Using QtCreator, there are so many examples on how I can do it. But using only QtDesigner 4 there are no examples. I have also tried creating a MainWindow and then having pushbuttons in that. I want to call a new pop up window when I click on a button (which is a custom form). I am using Eclipse CDT as the IDE. I have installed Qt plugin so that I can do both C++ and Qt development. The problem is I cannot use 'Form' to declare my custom form in header file of the mainwindow.

I read in few posts that this is not possible to do using only QtDesigner and also read it can be done using QObject::connect. Please can anyone help me to confirm if we can do it and if yes please can you provide me an example?

Comment: The answer of Dmitry Markin should help. Additionally i like to mention that you do not need qt creator or the qt plugin from ecplise to develop QT code because QT is, after the moc, standard C++. However, it helps to use the qt creator and i recommend and use it as IDE for qt and for (plain) C++ development.

Comment: @TWE: I am afraid, you are missing the point along with Dmitry. The OP is the best and most use of QtDesigner!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's definitely possible with C++. You'll need to `connect()` pushbutton's `clicked()` signal with a slot in your first form:

```
connect(pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(show2ndForm()));
```

The good place to connect is in your first form constructor.

In that slot just show your second form (for example, using `QDialog::exec()`):

```
void FirstForm::show2ndForm()
{
     static SecondForm *form = 0;
     if(!form)
         form = new SecondForm(this);
     form->exec();
}
```

You'll probably need to inherit your second form from `QDialog` to use this method and also create header and source files for your second form.

For modeless form instead of modal, use `form->show()` instead of `exec()`.

Comment: The OP was asking about QtDesigner for the connection as opposed to low-level code, or an IDE with editor like QtCreator.

Answer (score 0):

This is not complete possible if you need to customize a slot, but for simple operation where the existing slots are available, you can just use the signal-slot edit as below.

[image]

You can select the receiver object and then the correponding slot. I am providing further screenshot to show it is done for customized slots as well.

Right click with your mouse in the middle of the main window and the change signals and slots

[image]

Select the change signals and slot option

[image]

Use the Add button to add a new slot

[image]

Click on the OK button to conirm it once you chose the desired name

[image]

In the signal-slot editor double click on the desired object's slot, and it will show the available slots including your new custom slot.

[image]

Select your custom slot and you are done from the designer parts. Do not forget to actually implement that in your C++ code.

If you do not need a custom slot, and a built-in will suffice, you can select that off-hand without the previous steps. Those are provided for completeness.